# How do I set TabControls TabItem header FontSize

Tags: wpf, header, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a TabControl with a style that changes the FontSize of the Header of the TabItem. When I data bind the ItemsSource only the headers are affected by the FontSize. But when I use the same style on another TabControl and add the TabItems in XAML the FontSize is changed on all content in the TabItem. I want the style to work with both databound and non-databound TabItems.

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource VariablesTabControl}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}">
...
</TabControl>
```

MainSkin.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl" x:Key="VariablesTabControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource VariableTabItem}" />
    ...
</Style>


<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="VariableTabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Grid Name="Panel" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="120">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,2" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundMouseOver}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: `<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource VariableTabItem}" />` who is `VariableTabItem`, does your tab controls have styles that overrides its Template ?

Comment: Sorry, have changed the style name in the example. Now its what I have in my code.

Comment: OK, now the second question - does your tab controls have styles that overrides the `Template`, normally the properties you set on `TabItem` does not effect the Tab's Content, unless you change this behavior yourself.

Comment: I do not override the Template property of the TabControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a result of [Property Value Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you define the `TabItem`s in xaml something like this:

```
 <TabItem>
     <TabItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="TEST_HEADER1" />
     </TabItem.Header>
     <TextBlock Text="TEST_CONTENT1" />
 </TabItem>
```

Both `TextBox`es, the header, and the content are in the logical tree of the `TabItem` that means that any Inheritable property set on `TabItem` will be propagated down the tree to these `TextBox`es.

The `Foreground` and `FontSize` are Inheritable.

If you have something like:

```
  <TabItem Header="TEST_HEADER2">TEST_CONTENT2</TabItem>
```

you don't have any Elements in `TabItem`'s logical tree, the elements for the Header and the content will be auto generated, and the properties will not be inherited. 
But this type of declaring `TabItem`'s is not very useful, you usually need some advanced XAML as the items content so I think the best way to solve this is by changing all those text properties in `TabItem`'s `HeaderTemplate`, you can bind to `TabItem's` properties using the `RelativeSource`.

Comment: I used the HeaderTemplate to set the FontSize. Thanks!