# How can I trigger on 'IsSelected' from a TabItem's HeaderTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, tabcontrol

I've created a custom styled `TabControl` for my WPF application. This includes the following `Style` for the `TabItem`s:

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,2"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Basically, I want the header text to be size 14 and colored in white, except when the `TabItem` is selected (then it should be orange):
[image: Example of what the TabControl should look like]

I ran into a problem when I saw that the `TabItem`'s child control (which is not displayed in the screen above) has inherited `FontSize` and `Foreground`. After a quick search at SO, I came to this thread [(SO: How do I set TabControls TabItem header FontSize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844105/how-do-i-set-tabcontrols-tabitem-header-fontsize) and decided to use the HeaderTemplate, as recommended by the answerer 'Novitchi S'. This is my result:

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,2"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.Content>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentTextBlock" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </ContentPresenter.Content>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}">
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

On the positive side, `FontSize` and `Foreground` are working fine now. The only thing I can't get to work is to color the `TextBlock` orange when the tab is selected. My intuition is that the DataTrigger either can't find the `TemplatedParent` or the `TextBlock`, but I'm stuck.

What options do I have to acheive my goal?

Comment: Why use Mode=TemplatedParent, in a datatemplate, shouldn't you be doing {Binding Path=propertyOfTargetElement, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type typeOfTargetElement}}}

Comment: @TYY I have been always confused with all the different types of bindings, so I didn't came up with that. The `Trigger` condition is working fine now, thanks. However, the `TextBlock` color still won't change. Did I make another mistake, or is the `TextBlock` just out of the namescope?

Comment: @TYY Silly me, I forgot to add `Value="True"` to my `DataTrigger`. Works flawless now!

Comment: I did not catch that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so Problem #1

Incorrect binding Mode, don't use `Mode=TemplatedParent`, use

```
{ Binding Path=propertyOfTargetElement, 
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type typeOfTargetElement}
                 }
}
```

**

**
As for the #2  problem I would move the trigger into the textblock. Note I don't see the purpose of the contentpresenter in that datatemplate so remove it, unless it is there for a reason).

I would then do

```
 <TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
```

Comment: The ContentPresenter is left over from an example of what a HeaderTemplate should look like. I removed it now, thanks for pointing that out. :)