# how to set content of control in headertemplate for tabitem programmatically

Tags: wpf, tabs, header

I have tabs.

On each tab, I will use a header template that contains "textbox".

Now, how I can access this control programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clear clarification on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844105/how-do-i-set-tabcontrols-tabitem-header-fontsize?rq=1)!

The answer: My textbox in tab header can be access by its name as any control in the same tab.